# How can I find out the amount of open sessions programatically in Tomcat using Java?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, logging, timeout

Is it possible to find out the number of open sessions reliably in Tomcat (i.e. not only the amount of users who have logged in since [current time]-[session time out], but the number of sessions stored on the server)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this info using JMX. See [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/monitoring.html) for how to enable JMX and what variables to query.

Using an Ant JMX task you can use:

```
   <!-- get all sessions and split result as delimiter <em>SPACE</em> for easy
             access all session ids directly with ant property sessions.[0..n].
        -->
        <jmx:invoke
            name="Catalina:type=Manager,path=/ClusterTest,host=localhost" 
            operation="listSessionIds"
            resultproperty="sessions"
            echo="false"
            delimiter=" "
        />
```

but you can use other tools e.g. [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you need this info in your application, you can trace when sessions are created or destroyed by implementing HttpSessionListener and adding it to your server context.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html

Answer (score -1):

You can find this with the builtin Manager as well at http://server:8080/manager/status

If you don't have an admin login enabled, edit `conf/tomcat-users.xml` and add a user with `role="admin"`. More info in the Tomcat documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

Comment: The question is about getting the sessions programatically using Java.